# Two-relator products of cyclic groups

Tags: gr.group-theory, gt.geometric-topology, geometric-group-theory

In "A proof of the Scott–Wiegold conjecture on free products of cyclic groups" Howie proved that every one-relator product of three cyclic groups is nontrivial. Is there a now proven theorem that says every two-relator product of ($\geq$)n cyclic groups is nontrivial for some n? If not, how much is known about this?

Comment: Perhaps it's worth remarking that Howie conjectures that this should be true for n=5.