# Nontriviality of one-relator products

Tags: gr.group-theory, gt.geometric-topology

$\DeclareMathOperator\ncl{ncl}$When I attended a geometric group theory summer school, a question asked by the speaker reminded me of an old [question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/171776/two-relator-products-of-cyclic-groups) but shaped in a different manner:

> Given two nontrivial groups $A,B$ and $w \in A \ast B$. For any $k\geq 2$, is the quotient
> $(A\ast B)/\ncl(w^k)$ nontrivial, where $\ncl(w^k)$ is the normal closure of $w^k$?

This is true if $B = \mathbb{Z}$ and the projection of $w$ to $B =\mathbb{Z}$ is $\pm 1$. For $k\geq 4$, this was handled by a theorem of Howie.

It is not true in general when $k =1$. For example, let $A = \mathbb{Z}_2$ and $B = \mathbb{Z}_3$
and $w = ab^{-1}$. When $w$ becomes a relation, $a,b$ must be conjugate, but $a,b$ originally have orders $2$ and $3$, resp. It follows that $a = b$ are trivial elements and the group is trivial. I'm particularly interested in the following question

> When $k=1$, are there counterexamples if $A,B$ are torsion-free?

Comment: There are no counter-examples for $A$ torsion-free and $B\cong\mathbb{Z}$. This corresponds to the Kervaire-Laudenbach Conjecture for torsion-free groups, which was proven by Klyachko; see Fenn and Rourke, *Klyachko's methods and the solution of equations over torsion-free groups*, Enseign. Math. (2) 42 (1996), no. 1-2, 49–74.

Comment: @ADL: since this answers the question, you should post it as an answer!

Comment: @HJRW It isn't a complete solution, so wasn't sure! I've posted it now.

Comment: @ADL: For some reason I had it in mind that Klyahcko's solution should also work for "one-relator free products" as well as "one-relator HNN extensions", especially with the torsion hypothesis. :) Anyway, your answer certainly covers most situations.

Comment: @HJRW I can't see this immediately, so I'd have to think properly about it. Theorem 6.1 of Fenn and Rourke's paper proves the result for words $w$ of a certain form, but really, both in this theorem and in their whole paper, they're focusing on embedding $A$ (i.e. proving a Freiheitssatz) rather than proving non-triviality. So their methods are stronger than needed here, which makes me less confident that they can be applied.

Comment: Well Klyachko is sometimes active on MO, so perhaps he can comment!

Comment: I do not know.  The question is a weaker form of **Levin’s conjecture**: *if $A$ and $B$ are torsion-free groups and $w$ is not conjugate to elements of $A$, then $A$ embeds into the quotient.*

Comment: Corollary V.9.4 of Lyndon-Schupp implies that for a C’(1/6) free product of groups, each factor embeds and hence the group is non-trivial. https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-642-61896-3

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a partial answer: The Kervaire-Laudenbach Conjecture states that, for any group $A$, $(A\ast\mathbb{Z})/\operatorname{ncl}(w)$ is non-trivial. This was proven by Klyachko for torsion free groups $A$; see Fenn and Rourke, *Klyachko's methods and the solution of equations over torsion-free groups*, Enseign. Math. (2) 42 (1996), no. 1-2, 49–74 ([doi](http://dx.doi.org/10.5169/seals-87871)). Hence:

> There are no counter-examples for $A$ torsion-free and $B\cong Z$.

This can be easily generalised: A group is *indicable* if it surjects onto $\mathbb{Z}$. If $B$ is indicable, so $\phi:B\twoheadrightarrow\mathbb{Z}$, then the map $\phi$ induces a map $\overline{\phi}:(A\ast B)/\operatorname{ncl}(w)\twoheadrightarrow(A\ast\mathbb{Z})/\operatorname{ncl}(u)$ for some word $u\in A\ast\mathbb{Z}$. By Klyachko's theorem, we know the image is non-trivial so we immediately have:

> There are no counter-examples for $A$ torsion-free and $B$ indicable.

---

Klyachko's proof is really pretty, based on a "funny property" of spheres which "is so simple and funny" that, he claims, it could be included in a collection of puzzles or suggested as a problem for a school mathematical tournament. He phrased it in terms of car crashes, and you can find a MathOverflow discussion on it [here](https://mathoverflow.net/q/2372/6503). The paper of Fenn and Rourke I cited above is the best place to read about it though.

---

Added later: I asked Jim Howie if he knew what the status of this problem is, and he said he thought it open and very difficult (so there are no *known* counter-examples).

He also pointed to two papers of his - one with Brodskii from 1993, and the other with Edjvet from 2021. These prove that when $A,B$ are torsion-free, then they embed into $(A*B)/\operatorname{ncl}(w)$ if $w$ has free product length $\le 6$ (first paper) and $\le 8$ (second paper). These are innocuous-sounding results, but the one extra step took ~28 years, and both took quite a bit of work to prove.

Embedding results like these are typically referred to as *Freiheitssatz* and seem to be the main approach to problems of this form. For example the main result of Klyachko's paper is a Freiheitssatz for when $w$ has a specific form; the other cases follow from an easy observation. A Freiheitssatz is a priori stronger than a non-triviality result would be, however Jim points out that it is not clear how much stronger.

The papers are:

S. D. Brodskii and J. Howie, *One-relator products of torsion-free groups*, Glasgow Math. J. 35 (1993) 99-104 ([doi](https://doi.org/10.1017/S0017089500009617)).

M. Edjvet and J. Howie, *On singular equations over torsion-free groups* Internat. J. Algebra Comput. 31 (2021), 551-580 ([doi](https://doi.org/10.1142/S0218196721500272), [arXiv](https://arxiv.org/abs/2001.07634.pdf).

Comment: Thanks. It does cover many interesting cases so for sure an upvote. But since it’s a partial answer, I’d like to wait to see if someone can come up with a complete solution if there is one.

Comment: Note that if A is hyper linear, then Kervaire-Laudenbach also holds. https://doi.org/10.1515/jgth-2019-0167

Comment: Thanks for reporting on Howie’s comments. He is the expert on these things!